# how do i POST an empty array with curl in c?

Tags: arrays, c, json, curl, post

When trying to send an empty array using curl the array get's received as so `emptyArr['']`

with quote instead of being posted as an empty `emptyArr[]`

how do i post the `emptyArr` without the quote?

```c
#include <curl/curl.h>

CURL *curl;
      CURLcode res;
    
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
   
    /* get a curl handle */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
      /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
         just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
         data. */
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://someaddress.com");
      /* Now specify the POST data */
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "emptyArr[]");
   
      /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
      res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
      /* Check for errors */
      if(res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
   
      /* always cleanup */
      curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
```

Comment: This is tilde: `~`. Where do you see that?

Comment: oh sorry i translated it from another language

Comment: I think you mean quotes.

Comment: @Barmar oh ok  aren't quote this `" "`

Comment: Single quote: `'` double quote: `"`

Comment: @Barmar ah ok thank you

Comment: In your question, you state that this is being received: `emptyArr['']` However, that does not necessarily mean that this is actually getting sent by libcurl. Maybe the problem is in the receiving program, not the sending program? Maybe it is reinterpreting the sent data in some way?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel  i have posted the same array with nodejs and the server see's it as empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty arrays don't really exist in URL-encoded parameters. When you send an array, it's sent as:

```
name[]=firstElement&name[]=secondElement&name[]=thirdElement
```

An empty array means you don't send any of these, but then there's no parameter at all.

It's the responsibility of the server code to handle the nonexisting parameter and treat it as an empty array.

When you write

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "emptyArr[]");
```

it's being treated as

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "emptyArr[]=");
```

so you're creating an array with one element whose value is an empty string.

You should simply leave out the parameter entirely, and the server should treat it as empty.

Comment: Re: "Empty arrays don't really exist in URL-encoded parameters" ok so i guess that sending that empty array i not possible then :/  when i post json from nodejs it get's recieved as an empty array i guess i have to look up on how to post json in c instead.

Comment: That's JSON, not URL-encoded.